# How to add customized text in the graphs generated by Proc Gplot

Tags: sas

Can someone help me on how to add text to the graph that is generated by gplot procedure? I would like to add some statistics as the text highlighted in yellow from other procedures for better understanding.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: For GPLOT, I think you would look into ANNOTATE.  If you switch to SGPLOT, it would probably be easier.  Suggest you post sample data and code, which will make it easier for people to help you.  Could also search user group papers at lexjansen.com.

Comment: Check robslink.com for many, many examples with code. However, I would highly suggest you switch to SGPLOT not GPLOT as you'll get more control and better quality graphics.

Comment: text would be added via an annotate option.